# Using document.getSelection() to get data to array like document.getSelection().toString() does for strings

Tags: html, angularjs, arrays

I have an table in angular JS with filtering. I want to have only the selected data in the table in an array rows[] of arrays cell[]. This is why i cannot just export the table data.
I have tried the document.getSelection().toString() class and then .split but this failed as the elements in the table might consist of more than one word with blanks in between.

Is there a way to loop thru the object i get from document.getSelection() and distinguish between rows and cells?

With this i get the data as text, but i need an array:

```
    var txt = '';
    if (document.getSelection) {
        txt = document.getSelection().toString(); 
    } else if (document.selection) {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
```

Here i get the object:

```
    if (document.getSelection) {
        txt = document.getSelection(); 
    } else if (document.selection) {
        txt = document.selection.createRange();
    }
    console.log(txt)
```

Selection { anchorNode: , anchorOffset: 0, focusNode: , focusOffset: 3, isCollapsed: false, rangeCount: 1, caretBidiLevel: 0 }

Comment: provide your code

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer was quite easy. I just had to use the document.getSelection().toString() function and use the split("/n") to get all the lines into an array, then i used split again to separate the elements by the tab that is added between column cells.

```
var tmp = [];
var rows = [];
var cells = [];
tmp = txt.split("\n");
for (var i=0; i<tmp.length; i++) {
  cells.length = 0;
  cells = tmp.split("\t");
  rows.push(cells);
}
```